# How to add measurement details while line drawing in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add the length of the start point and endpoint of the line geometry. I have a line but I have no idea how to show some unit measurement data in the form of the text while drawing the wall in mouse move itself.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/a21ey9y6/)

[image]

```
var renderer, scene, camera;
var line;
var count = 0;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();

init();
animate();

function init() {

  // info
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  info.style.position = 'absolute';
  info.style.top = '30px';
  info.style.width = '100%';
  info.style.textAlign = 'center';
  info.style.color = '#fff';
  info.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  info.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  info.style.zIndex = '1';
  info.style.fontFamily = 'Monospace';
  info.innerHTML = "three.js - animated line using BufferGeometry";
  document.body.appendChild(info);

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

  // geometry
  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  var MAX_POINTS = 500;
  positions = new Float32Array(MAX_POINTS * 3);
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

  // material
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 2
  });

  // line
  line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(line);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
}

// update line
function updateLine() {
  positions[count * 3 - 3] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 - 2] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 - 1] = mouse.z;
  line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

// mouse move handler
function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0;
  mouse.unproject(camera);
  if( count !== 0 ){
    updateLine();
  }
}

// add point
function addPoint(event){
  console.log("point nr " + count + ": " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y + " " + mouse.z);
  positions[count * 3 + 0] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 + 1] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 + 2] = mouse.z;
  count++;
  line.geometry.setDrawRange(0, count);
  updateLine();
}

// mouse down handler
function onMouseDown(evt) {
  // on first click add an extra point
  if( count === 0 ){
      addPoint();
  }
  addPoint();
}

// render
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the measurement like the above.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `CSS2D` labels. You can assign a regular HTML `<div>` to act as a label. It displays flat on top of your `<canvas>` renderer without rotations so it's always facing the camera. See here for a demo on how to set up your CSS2DRenderer:
https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label

All you'd have to do is take the average of 2 Vector3s, and assign that as your label's position.

```js
// Get distance and midpoint
var distance = vectorA.distanceTo(vectorB);

var midpoint = new Vector3();
midpoint.copy(vectorA);
midpoint.add(vectorB).multiplyScalar(0.5);

// Create label, set distance and position
const labelDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
labelDiv.className = 'label';
labelDiv.textContent = "Distance: " + distance;
labelDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
const distLabel = new CSS2DObject( labelDiv );
distLabel.position.copy( midpoint );
cssScene.add( distLabel );
```

Comment: `midpoint.addScalar(vectorB)` won't work, as `.addScalar()` expects a float value. Seems, it's just a typo, as it has to be just `.add()`. Kind of a one-liner for `midpoint` will be like this: `var midpoint = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(vectorA, vectorB).multiplyScalar(0.5)`.

Comment: @prisoner849 doh, you're right, it's just `add()`. Fixed! Here's an even shorter one: `var midpoint = vectorA.clone().add(vectorB).multiplyScalar(0.5);` :)

Comment: can you add it on the fiddle if possible @prisoner849

Comment: @NoobDeveloper you’re asking us to do your work for you?

Comment: haha! nope! Done it myself! Thank you for your help @Marquizzo